# How To Build a Hello World For Nintendo 64?

Tags: assembly, mips, nintendo

I'm reading [MIPS Assembly Language Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131420445), but now I want to build a simple "game" for *[Nintendo 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64)*. I want to print a `Hello, World` to the screen, but someone can help with this. As I don't have nothing to start.

*I've choose for Nintendo 64 because of my friend told me that it uses MIPS and I've already have the emulator.*

Comment: From a deleted link-only answer: http://nintendo64.dcemu.co.uk/ (Nintendo 64 Homebrew News Forum) apparently "seems to have everything you need".

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to, if from scratch, set up the GPU ([Reality-Coprocessor/RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCP_%28chip%29)) of the N64.

[This documentation covers a lot of it](http://www.dragonminded.com/n64dev/Reality%20Coprocessor.pdf), including memory-mapped registers/hardware control registers for the GPU, memory-maps in general. Bear in mind that this is no easy, walk in the park task, but it's feasible.

Are there any other methods? Probably, but as far as from doing it all from pure scratch you can probably head over to a ROM hacking site/community and maybe someone there can explain the gritty details in a nicer, more applicable way.